# Iterating and calculating with fields using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, iteration, replace

Inside my layer there are fields like this:

```
name    |    data       |    length
name_a  |    field_a_x  |    ...
name_b  |    field_b_x  |    ...
name_c  |    field_c_x  |    ...
name_d  |    field_d_x  |    ...
```

Is it possible to iterate only over the **data**-column, get the fields into a list and replace the data after calculating (or doing something else...)? The calculating-part will be easy but I'm having trouble understanding how to get and afterwards replace the data?

This is what I got so far...

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer_name = "ExampleLayer"
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
ftrs = layer.getFeatures()

list_old = []
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    list_old.append(feat['data'])
```

Comment: hello, can you add the result you are waiting for or an example of expression you would like to use ?

Comment: @CorentinLemaitre The new list could be anything actually! My problem is how to get the data into the field (updating)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
feats = [f for f in lyr.getFeatures()] #List all features

#names = [f['KOMMUNNAMN'] for f in feats] #List values in KOMMUNNAMN field
#['Kiruna', 'Pajala', 'Gällivare', 'Jokkmokk', 'Boden']

fieldindex = lyr.fields().indexFromName('KOMMUNNAMN')
attrMap = {}

for f in feats:
    attrMap[f.id()] = {fieldindex:f['KOMMUNNAMN'].upper()}

#attrMap
#{0: {3: 'KIRUNA'}, 1: {3: 'PAJALA'}, 2: {3: 'GÄLLIVARE'}, 3: {3: 'JOKKMOKK'}, 4: {3: 'BODEN'}}
lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attrMap)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!